# How to use Phonetic Symbols in LaTex

Tags: latex

How to use **inverted A** character(Phonetic Symbol) in an equation in LaTex? Do I have to use any specific package for it? I used \textinvsca, but it says "undefined control sequence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a myriad of ways you can achieve this. Most notably, consult [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764).

This reveals you need [`tipa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tipa) (more specifically, `\usepackage{tipx}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipx}
\begin{document}
A\textsc{a}\textinvsca\textsc{a}A
\end{document}
```

You can also rotate-and-scale a regular `A`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\textinvsca}{%
  \reflectbox{%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{%
      \resizebox{!}{.35\baselineskip}{\textsc{A}}}}}
\begin{document}
A\textsc{a}\textinvsca\textsc{a}A
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\forall` is the universal quantifier:
[image]